# How to check my address balance in regtest?

Tags: bitcoin-core, address, regtest

I have created a regtest address and I want to check it's balance.

I have run the commands:

1. -regtest generate 101
2. -regtest getbalance
3. -regtest sendtoaddress n4MN27Lk7Yh3pwfjCiAbRXtRVjs4Uk67fG 10.00
4. -regtest generate 6
5. -regtest getbalance n4MN27Lk7Yh3pwfjCiAbRXtRVjs4Uk67fG

after the 5th step the balance is still 0.

Why this happened since I have already sent 10 BTC to my address?
Do I have to sign any outputs in order to claim the bitcoins?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument for `getbalance` is not an address. It is for an account, which is not the same as an address. To get the entire wallet balance, do `getbalance` with no arguments.

Comment: @ Andrew the getbalance with no arguments is for the entire wallet.But how can I chech the balance for a particular public key/address?

Comment: You can't. You have to add that address to an account (aka give it a label). Then you can use getbalance to get the balance of that account, and if it only has one address, it will be the balance of that address.

Comment: now make sense!

Comment: use bitcoind -regtest -txindex and bitcoin-tx